Partial image bulge effect in python
I want to apply bulge effect on specific region of an image, like making the eye bigger or like bloat effect of Photoshop liquify filter using python. sth like this :
https://imgur.com/nBswbO2

this post perfectly implemented bulge effect on whole image, but how to apply it partially in Python?

this is graphics, not computer vision. use a graphics library. use the picture as a texture onto a mesh. deform the mesh. draw the scene. -- if you want to use OpenCV for this, expect to do a lot more work to get it done. it is not made for this. wrong tool for the job.

@ChristophRackwitz Any graphics library you know for this task? thx.

OpenGL, anything using OpenGL and exposing those abilities, ...

Something like this?
from skimage.transform import warp

def transform(xy, w, h, p, s):
  cx, cy = w, h
  r = np.sqrt((xy[:,0] - cx)**2 + (xy[:,1] - cy)**2)  # to polar coordinates
  a = np.arctan2(xy[:,0] - cx, xy[:,1] - cy)
  rn = r**p / s # bulge
  xy[:,0] = (rn*np.cos(a) + cx) # back to cartesian
  xy[:,1] = (rn*np.sin(a) + cy)
  return xy

im = imread('lena.jpg')
im_bulge = warp(im, transform, map_args={'w':im.shape[1]//2, 'h':im.shape[0]//2, 'p':1.75, 's':50})
plt.imshow(np.hstack((im, im_bulge)))


The parameters p and s can be varied to change the extent of bulge effect.
For partial bulging you may try masking the image appropriately and apply / mask the bulge effect.
EDIT (with mask)
As mentioned in the comment section, we can use a mask radius (r_mask, tune the parameter to get the desired output) inside which the warp transform is to be applied, the outside pixels remain as they are (undergo identity transform), below is slightly modified code to achieve the same:
def transform_with_mask(xy, w, h, p, s, r_mask):
  cx, cy = h, w
  r = np.sqrt((xy[:,0] - cx)**2 + (xy[:,1] - cy)**2)
  a = np.arctan2(xy[:,0] - cx, xy[:,1] - cy)
  rn = r**p / s
  oxy = xy.copy()
  xy[:,0] = (rn*np.cos(a) + cx)
  xy[:,1] = (rn*np.sin(a) + cy)
  region = (xy[:,0]-cx)**2 + (xy[:,1]-cy)**2 > r_mask**2 # outside mask
  xy[region,:] = oxy[region,:]
  return xy

with the following output:
im_bulge_partial = warp(im, transform_with_mask, \
                        map_args={'w':im.shape[1]//2+5, 'h':im.shape[0]//2+5, \
                                  'p':2, 's':15, 'r_mask':5})
plt.imshow(np.hstack((im, im_bulge_partial ))), plt.axis('off')


For example, the image with bulge can be fixed (by removing / undoing the bulge effect) with inverse bulge transform using the same function (by carefully choosing the parameters p, s and r_mask), as shown below:
im = imread('tO7xd.jpg')
im = im / im.max()
im_unbulge = warp(im, transform_with_mask, map_args={'w':328, 'h':405, 'p':0.5, 's':1/9, 'r_mask':80})



It's working for whole image and with im_bulge = warp(im, transform, map_args={'w':im.shape[1]//2, 'h':im.shape[0]//2}) but It's not working with for example im_bulge = warp(im, transform, map_args={'w':100, 'h':100}). I want to bulge only a circle around a point for example center of an eye

@MrPixel One workaround is to use a mask image for the desired region  (e.g., a single eye) to be bulged, use it to extract the corresponding part of the bulged output image and then combine it with the remaining part of the original image. The center coordinates (cx, cy) need to be adjusted properly so that they are at the center of the eye to be bulged, e.g.

or devise a mapping function with a more localized effect.

this isn't computer vision. I have removed that tag.

@ChristophRackwitz anyway, I haven't found any solution for that yet. but as far as it is a photoshop filter (Liquify - bloat effect), It can be a computer vision task.

@Mr Pixel Modified the code as per your requirement
